# Why does decrease the quality of text when we use transform: rotate?

Tags: html, css, rotation

Why does a decrease in quality?

There's no way to fix it?

```css
.circle1,
.circle2 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  font-family: "Georgia";
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.circle1 div,
.circle2 div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle1 div:first-child,
.circle2 div:first-child {
  background-color: #555;
  color: gold;
}

.circle1 div:last-child,
.circle2 div:last-child {
  background-color: gold;
  color: #222;
}

.circle2 span {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Without it, rotate not applies(since span is a inline element)*/
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle1">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="circle2">
  <div><span>one</span></div>
  <div><span>two</span></div>
</div>
<!-- spans for applying
     a 'rotate(-15deg)' to texts -->
```

Comment: This may well be very subjective, for example it looks okay on both my iPad and my Pixel. I can’t check my desktop at the moment, but I’d imagine it’s monitor, platform, os and browser dependent.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, you're right. for example, it decreases in Chrome too, but in Firefox its quality is lower.

Comment: It's looking fine on my laptop (Windows10 Edge and Firefox).